# adding value attribute on src tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a blank img src

`<img src="" id="preview" width="350" height="350"/>`

now i want to append here src url

I am using this code but not work

```
$("#preview img").each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
        img.attr("preview",img.attr("src"));
        img.attr("src",imgurl);
});
```

my full function

```
function editRetailer(functionData)
{

    id = functionData.id;
    store = functionData.url;
    imgurl=baseUrl+"/uploads/"+store;

    $("#preview img").each(function () {
            var img = $(this);
            img.attr("preview",img.attr("src"));
            img.attr("src",imgurl);
    }); 


    $('#rq').val(id);


    $('div#styledModal3').load(function(){
        $(this).modal({
            keyboard:true,
            backdrop:true
        });
    }).modal('show');

}
```

I cant understand why not work

Comment: What do you mean by : "this code does not work"? Have you got an error or does it work differently than expected, ...?

Comment: If you are targeting more than one image, they shouldn't have the same id. Id must be unique per element; you can use class instead.

Comment: `$("#preview img")` is trying to select an image that's a descendant of an element with the ID of "preview". In your code example you show us an image *with* the ID of "preview" (`<img src="" id="preview" width="350" height="350"/>`), so that selector can't possibly work.